# Todo React JS App 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need to create a React app that would display a text input for the user, where they will be able to write a task with a button displayed beside the input. When clicked, this button should add the user’s input to a list of to do items. Blank items should not be added to the list. Each list item must display a checkbox, and the task that the user wrote. When checking off the checkbox, the list item should be removed from the list. Also I'm getting the following error: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KqHN.png)
My code:

```js
App.js:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyList from './MyList.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { task };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('SUBMITTED', this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MyList
          name="task"
          currentTask={this.state.task}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

MyList.js:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import App from "./App.js";

class MyList extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { task };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('SUBMITTED', this.state);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                My Task List
                <input type="text" name="task" />
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add</button>
                <br />
                { this.handleChange }
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default MyList;
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.  the code you posted doesn't have any of the functionality that you are asking about in the first half of your question, and you are getting an error that you didn't even write in the question body (screenshots are rarely useful for showing error messages here).  If your goal is to solve the error, then posting the error text would help.  if, instead, your goal is to get *implementation help*, your question feels too broad.

Comment: So, it appears as though you've incorporated the answer you received into the code you have and changed the question. Please don't do that. You've essentially made the answerer's work look silly, because someone else coming along sees an answer which is already in the question. If you have a new question, ask a new question. You can reference this question, but be sure the new question stands on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to initialize the task state with an initial value that can be `null` or an empty string like so:

```
this.state = { task : '' }
```

secondary, you must put the `this.handleChange` method on the `onChange` of the input like :

```
<input type="text" name="task" onChange={this.handleChange} />.
```

check the code for more details: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pp127xm3zq)

```js
class ListItem extends React.Component {

  render (){
      return(
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.props.onCheckBoxChange} />
          <span>{this.props.text}</span>
        </li>
      )
  }
  
}

class MyList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.tasks.map(task => {
          return <ListItem key={task.id} text={task.text} onCheckBoxChange={()=>this.props.deleteListItem(task.id)} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      tasks : [] 
    };

    this.input = null;
  }

  addItemList(e){
    // APPEND THE ITEM TO THE TASKS ARRAY
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      tasks: [
          ...prevState.tasks,
          {
            id : new Date().getTime(),
            text : this.input.value
          }
        ]
    }))
  }

  deleteItem(itemId){

    this.setState((prevState)=>({
      tasks: prevState.tasks.filter((item)=>item.id !== itemId)
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          My Task List
          <input ref={(ref)=>{this.input = ref}} type="text" />
          <button onClick={this.addItemList.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        </div>

        <MyList
            tasks={this.state.tasks}
            deleteListItem={(itemId)=>this.deleteItem(itemId)}
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}


const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Got it, but still don't understand how to implement the actual list with checkboxes, by clicking on which, the task would be deleted

Comment: Gives the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to update the link in the answer, please re-check now

Comment: Do I need to change the code if I put it in App.js file?

Comment: It depends on your project files structure.
just pay attention to the render method in the bottom of  the index.js ( may be you need to remove it )

Comment: In error it shows that there's something wrong with this line:
{this.props.tasks.map(task => {

Comment: ( There is no error in the code ) I added a code snippet on the answer.

Comment: That error fixed and now it doesn't like my standard index.js file(

./src/index.js
8:36-39 "export 'default' (imported as 'App') was not found in './App'